# How do I call one class from a different class in Javascript? (beginner question)

Tags: javascript, class

I am working on a binary search tree and I am having difficulty calling the Node class from within my BST class. It seems like it should be an easy solution but I am having difficulty finding it. Anyways, the problem is right at the beginning of my insert() function with this line- newNode = new Node(val); giving me this error- Uncaught ReferenceError: newNode is not defined at BST.insert

The only solution I have been able to find is to use a static function within the Node class but I haven't tested this yet as it seems like a poor workaround imo as I don't want the Nodes to have any function beyond populating my Binary Tree and I'd just as soon convert it back to ES5 connotation where it worked just fine. Anyways, here is my code-

```js
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}
class BST {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  insert(val) {
    newNode = new Node(val);
    if (this.root == null) {
      this.root = newNode;
      return this;
    }
    runner = this.root
    done = false;
    while (!done) {
      if (val == runner.value)
        done = true;
      if (val < runner.value) {
        if (runner.left == null) {
          runner.left = newNode;
          done = true;
        } else
          runner = runner.left
      } else {
        if (runner.right == null) {
          runner.right = newNode;
          done = true;
        } else
          runner = runner.right
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
  preTraverse(runner) {
    if (!runner)
      runner = this.root;
    console.log(runner.value + " ")
    if (runner.left == null && runner.right == null)
      return this;
    else if (runner.left == null)
      return preTraverse(runner.right);
    else if (runner.right == null)
      return preTraverse(runner.left);
    else
      return (preTraverse(runner.left) + preTraverse(runner.right))
  }
}
var first = new BST();
first.root = new Node(30);
first.insert(20).insert(40).insert(50).insert(25).insert(10).insert(45)
console.log(first)
```

Comment: You might try `const newNode = new Node(val);`

Comment: Also a couple others will need `let`. Or use `var` for all of them.

Comment: All members of a class should be prefixed with `this`.

Comment: The error isn't about accessing the Node class, it's just that the variable "newNode" has not been declared. Changing the line to `let newNode = new Node(val);` will resolve this error. (You'll need to make similar changes where you introduce `runner` and `done`.) Let us know how your project turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah wow, that's the problem with switching back and forth between languages, I forget the little things and make stupid mistakes like that. Problem solved, thanks for the help!